# Frequency Table of Categorical Variables as a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I would like to create a frequency Table of all Categorical Variables as a Data Frame in R. I would like to find the frequency and percentage of each survey response (grouped by condition, as well as the total frequency). I would like to generate this as a data frame.

An example of the desired frequency count out for just ONE variable ("q1"). I want a similar freq count for most of the variables in my data:
[image]

I have data such as this. The actual data has many more categorical variables.

```
library(readr)
data_in <- read_table2("treatment_cur   q13_3   q14_1   q14_2   q14_3   q14_4   q14_5   q14_6   q14_7   q14_8   q14_9   q14_10  q14_11  q14_12  q14_13  q14_14  q14_15
Control 3   2   3   6   5   6   6   6   4   5   5   5   4   6   6   5
Control 2   4   5   6   5   6   5   5   6   4   5   5   6   5   4   6
Treatment   3   1   2   6   4   6   5   4   6   4   6   1   5   6   4   6
Control 3   2   3   6   4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5   5   6
Control NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Control 4   6   5   6   5   6   5   6   6   5   1   1   6   5   5   6
Control 3   3   2   2   3   3   6   6   4   6   5   5   3   6   6   2
Treatment   2   3   2   3   1   3   1   1   1   3   3   3   3   3   3   1
Control 3   5   5   6   3   6   3   3   3   2   2   1   4   2   3   4
Control 2   1   1   1   1   1   4   4   1   1   1   1   1   4   4   2
Control 4   3   4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
Control 4   2   6   6   4   6   5   6   6   5   6   5   6   6   6   6
Control 2   2   3   3   2   3   5   6   5   3   3   3   3   5   3   2
Control 3   2   4   3   4   5   4   4   5   3   3   5   4   5   5   4
Treatment   2   2   2   2   2   3   1   1   2   2   3   2   3   3   2   3
Control 4   3   3   3   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
Treatment   2   1   3   3   2   1   3   4   2   2   3   3   2   3   3   3
Treatment   4   2   6   4   4   2   3   5   4   5   1   1   5   4   4   5
Control 3   3   3   4   4   4   4   5   3   2   5   4   5   5   4   4
Control 4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5   6   6   5
Control 2   2   3   6   2   5   1   2   4   4   1   1   6   4   4   6
Treatment   4   3   3   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
Treatment   4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
Treatment   1   1   2   4   4   4   1   1   1   1   1   1   6   1   1   6
Treatment   3   2   3   3   2   6   6   6   6   3   3   2   4   5   5   6
Control 2   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   2   2   1
Control 1   3   3   3   1   1   5   5   2   4   5   5   4   1   2   5
Treatment   3   4   4   5   5   4   4   4   3   5   3   4   4   6   6   5
Control NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Control 2   2   4   6   2   4   2   2   3   5   4   4   4   3   3   5
Treatment   1   1   2   1   1   1   1   1   6   1   1   1   6   2   3   6
Treatment   2   6   1   4   4   1   1   2   2   2   1   2   1   2   2   2
Treatment   3   3   4   4   4   6   6   5   4   6   3   5   5   6   6   4
Treatment   2   1   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
Control 4   3   4   6   4   6   4   5   6   3   4   4   6   6   4   6
Control 4   4   3   6   2   5   2   2   4   3   1   6   5   5   5   5
Control NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Treatment   2   3   3   6   5   6   1   2   6   5   4   4   5   5   5   6
Control 4   6   6   6   6   6   5   5   5   5   5   6   5   5   5   5
Treatment   2   1   1   3   1   3   4   4   4   4   1   4   3   4   4   4
Treatment   2   1   3   3   3   3   4   6   5   4   5   5   4   6   6   5
Control 4   6   6   6   6   6   5   5   5   6   6   5   5   5   6   6
Control NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
Control 4   2   2   4   2   4   6   6   6   6   4   6   5   6   6   5
Control 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
Treatment   3   4   2   5   5   5   6   5   5   5   5   5   5   6   6   6
Control NA  2   4   4   4   4   4   3   4   6   4   5   4   6   4   4
Control 2   2   2   3   1   3   4   1   1   1   2   1   3   3   3   3
Treatment   2   2   2   3   2   2   3   3   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Control 3   3   3   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   5   6   6   6   6   6
Treatment   2   1   2   2   2   1   2   2   1   1   2   1   2   2   1   3
Treatment   4   5   5   6   6   5   5   6   5   5   4   5   5   4   4   5
Control 3   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Treatment   3   3   4   4   4   6   3   2   5   3   2   2   5   6   5   6
Control 4   4   3   3   6   3   6   6   3   2   4   4   4   4   4   4
Treatment   4   1   3   4   4   4   5   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
Control 4   4   5   6   5   5   4   6   6   6   6   5   6   6   6   6
Treatment   3   3   4   6   6   6   6   6   5   6   6   5   4   6   6   4
Control 4   4   6   6   4   6   6   6   6   4   4   3   5   6   6   6
Control 4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
Treatment   4   5   5   6   6   6   6   6   5   5   6   6   5   5   6   6
Treatment   4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
Control 2   1   2   1   1   1   1   3   1   4   4   1   1   1   1   1
Treatment   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
Treatment   4   6   5   5   5   5   5   6   5   4   5   4   4   5   5   4
Treatment   4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6
Control 4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
Treatment   4   5   6   6   6   5   6   6   6   5   6   6   6   6   6   6
Control 2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Treatment   3   3   2   5   4   4   5   6   6   4   5   5   4   5   4   6
Treatment   4   5   4   4   4   5   5   6   4   5   4   3   6   6   6   6
Control 1   2   3   2   1   4   1   1   3   1   3   3   3   3   4   4
Control 3   6   6   6   6   6   5   1   5   6   5   6   6   6   6   6
Control 1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
Control 4   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
")
```

My current solution is too complicated. If I wanted to know the frequency of variables from q13_3:q14_9, I know that I can do something like this to find it:

```
library(tables)
varList <- 2:11
data_in[varList] <- lapply(data_in[varList], factor,exclude = NULL)

  lapply(varList,function(x,df,byVar){ 
    tabular((Factor(df[[x]],paste(colnames(df)[x])) + 1) ~ ((Factor(df[[byVar]],paste(byVar)))*((n=1) + Percent("col"))),
            data= df) 
  },data_in,"treatment_cur")
```

Below is a snippet of what my current output looks like. The problem is that the output is a list of a list which cannot be exported into a single excel sheet. I have to manually copy everything from the console onto an excel file.

```
       treatment_cur                          
       Control               Treatment        
 q14_8 n             Percent n         Percent
 1      6             13.953  4         12.50 
 2      4              9.302  4         12.50 
 3      5             11.628  2          6.25 
 4      6             13.953  4         12.50 
 5      5             11.628  7         21.88 
 6     13             30.233 11         34.38 
 NA     4              9.302  0          0.00 
 All   43            100.000 32        100.00 

[[10]]
                                              
       treatment_cur                          
       Control               Treatment        
 q14_9 n             Percent n         Percent
 1      6             13.953  4         12.50 
 2      6             13.953  4         12.50 
 3      4              9.302  4         12.50 
 4      6             13.953  5         15.62 
 5      5             11.628  8         25.00 
 6     12             27.907  7         21.88 
 NA     4              9.302  0          0.00 
 All   43            100.000 32        10
```

This works alright, but I want to:

1. Find the total frequency of each variable value as well (treatment + condition) as an additional column (as seen in the image above);
2. I do not like the function I am using to produce this output. I want to export this into an excel file, but since this output is actually a list of lists (it cannot be exported to excel), and I am finding it quite cumbersome to copy and paste these values from the console into excel. I would like an easier way of finding these frequencies! Surely R has a better way of doing this...

Any help is MUCH appreciated!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this would be to explore using the `gtsummary` package.

using your code above you can produce a table quite easily with counts and percentages:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(readr)
library(flextable)


tbl_summary(data_in, by = "treatment_cur") %>% 
    add_overall() %>% 
    as_flex_table() %>% 
    flextable::save_as_docx(., path = "G:/test.docx")
```

If you just run:

```
tbl_summary(data_in, by = "treatment_cur") %>% 
        add_overall()
```

you will see the table it generates for you. The extra code after that makes it so that it is able to be exported to a docx file. From there you can copy that into excel. This generates the counts you requested and you can determine if it is a simpler implementation.

Another alternative is to write directly to a csv file:

```
tbl_summary(data_in, by = "treatment_cur") %>% 
    add_overall() %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    readr::write_csv( .,path = "G:/test.csv")
```

OR
if you really need everything in separate columns you can separate the n and percents into two tables, merge them and then write to csv.

```
#keep counts only
ncount <- tbl_summary(data_in, by = "treatment_cur",
            statistic = all_categorical()~ "{n}") %>% 
    add_overall() 

#keep pcts only

pctdata <- tbl_summary(data_in, by = "treatment_cur",
            statistic = all_categorical()~ "{p}%") %>% 
  add_overall() 
#combine and output

tbl_merge(list(ncount, pctdata)) %>% 
      as_tibble() %>% 
      readr::write_csv(., "G:/test2.csv")
```

Edit:
Another way to approach this is with the janitor package. You can adorn counts and percentages pretty easily and merge the datasets together. After that it is easy to export to a csv/Excel. One downside here is you have to loop through your variables to get a table for each and then combine them together, however the code below is a good start to create it:

```
library(janitor)


datatry <- data_in %>% 
          janitor::tabyl( q13_3,treatment_cur) %>% 
          adorn_totals("col") %>% 
          adorn_totals("row")

datatry2 <- data_in %>% 
  janitor::tabyl( q13_3,treatment_cur) %>% 
  janitor::adorn_percentages(denominator = 'col') %>% 
  adorn_totals("row") %>% 
  adorn_totals("col") %>% 
  mutate(Total = ifelse(is.na(q13_3), Total, ifelse(q13_3 == 'Total',1, Total)))

datatry3 <- inner_join(datatry, datatry2, by = 'q13_3') %>%
            mutate(variable ='q13_3')
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike. This is really close to what I want! I also need to see the "Total" of each column for each question. Right now, I would have to read out the tibble and re-read it in to calculate the totals. (The column names of the tbl_merge are identical so I can't directly manipulate it).

Comment: The question/variables names are in the same column as their values, so I can't manipulate the tibble/dataframe to group by the question and find the total.

Comment: @NewBee the total is in the header column and not its own separate row. Do you need the total number because it will change based on missing values? How do you want missing values handled included or excluded from the table? I can also change the labels of the columns if that would help.

Comment: yes I would need the total row for each variable separately, even though it will likely be the same value for each variable. The "Unkown" or "missing value" should be included in the total!

Comment: the other issue is that the missing/unknown percentages are not getting calculated correctly.

Comment: @NewBee yes by default `gtsummary` does not include the unknown values into the percentages

Comment: you can change a missing option in tbl_summary to 'always' so they are included in the %s, I updated my answer

Comment: I have a different related question here, in case you might have some time! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63840164/using-tbl-summary-to-create-summary-statistics-with-labels

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you constructed `data_in` as above:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# reformat
tt <- data_in$treatment_cur
data_in$treatment_cur <- NULL

data_in %>% map(function(a)
{
    ret <- data.frame(Treatment.n=rep(0, 6), Control.n=rep(0, 6))
    b <- table(a[tt=="Treatment"])
    ret[names(b), "Treatment.n"] <- b
    b <- table(a[tt=="Control"])
    ret[names(b), "Control.n"] <- b
    ret$Treatment.percent <- ret$Treatment.n / sum(ret$Treatment.n)
    ret$Control.percent <- ret$Control.n / sum(ret$Control.n)
    ret
}) %>% do.call(what=cbind)
```

It assumes answers data is \in 1..6 and NA are ignored.

Comment: thanks, this was useful! I did want an answer that did not involve a function.. so I am going to award the answer to the person who suggested tbl_summary.